# NoMethodError (undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

NoMethodError (undefined method `projects' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/project_controller.rb:8:in`index'

> ```
> Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
> (21.7ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.2ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
> (3.6ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb
> within rescues/layout (89.7ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb
> (0.6ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb
> within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb
> within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb
> within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (51.7ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb
> within layouts/javascript (1.2ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.9ms)   Rendered
> /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (116.8ms)
> ```

Here is a project controller:

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController

  before_action :confirm_logged_in

  before_action :find_company


  def index

    @projects = @company.projects.sorted
  end

  def show

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new

    @project = Project.new()
    @project_count = Project.count + 1
    @companys = Company.order("position ASC")
  end

  def create

    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else

      @project_count = Project.count + 1
      @companys = Company.order("position ASC")
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project_count = Project.count 
    @companys = Company.order("position ASC")
  end

  def update

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else

      @project_count = Project.count
      @companys = Company.order("position ASC")
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def delete

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destory

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.destroy
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end


  private 

  def project_params

   params.require(:project).permit(:name, :position, :type_of_project, :description, :no_of_tasks)
  end

  def find_company

    if params[:company_id]
      @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means `@company` is `nil`. The company is from the method `find_company`, you can either correct your `find_company` logic, or provide a `company_id` parameter in your request. You can also adjust the `index` method to get all projects if `@company` is nil like so:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all.sorted
end
```

It all depends on how you want to load the projects.

Answer (score 0):

What is your link url or button url to go the index page. You need to pass `:company_id` params to make it work.

e.g.

`projects_path(:company_id => Company.first.id)`